# A (False) Proof That ℙ≠ℕℙ

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

**Why the following proof is invaid?**

Using C-like pseudo-program:
**Definition**: bool S(Func, UInt): S(f,n)==true iff ∃x, x<=n, F(x)==true 
F is defined in ℙ as a certificate function, so S is in ℕℙ. 

Now, if S∈ℙ, then, there exists a function F∈ℙ: 
bool F(UInt n) { 
return !S(F,n);  
} 

Given an UInt m: 
If F(m)==true, then, S(F,m)==false. From definition of S: ∀x<=m, F(x)==false. 
This contradicts the premise F(m)==true when x==m. 

If F(m)==false, then, S(F,m)==true. From definition of S: ∃x<=m, F(x)==true. 
Assume ∃m',m'<m, F(m')==true, but previous proof showed this will cause 
contradiction when m>=1. 

Conclusion: As x>=1, S and F cannot be both in ℙ, thus ℙ≠ℕℙ. 
QED. 

**Note**: This proof is similar to the Halting Problem proof.

Comment: Aside from the other answer: Your idea (as is the case with the standard proof of the undecidability of the halting problem) is based on a method called diagonalization. No such idea can resolve $\mathsf P$ vs $\mathsf{NP}$ by itself; look for the Baker-Gill-Solovay theorem to understand why.

Comment: The HP is mentioned is for quicker understanding. The idea and method of this proof does 
not rely on diagonalization method or any other theorem (no dependency, so to 
speak). The logical absurdity is shown in this proof. One can write an ACTUAL program or TM to test the logic.

Comment: Please try to learn what are and are not $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ before trying to prove they are different. If you cannot understand that they are not sets of functions, you will not go anywhere with your proofs.

Comment: Sorry guys, I see the error of this proof This post may be deleted by me latter.

Comment: Can you phrase your text in a form of a question? I'm voting to close as unclear for the time being as there is no question here, just a claim.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathsf{P}$, $\mathsf{NP}$ or $\mathsf{EXP}$ are not sets of functions, but sets of problems. As an example, consider the following problem $\texttt{SORTED}$:

> Input: an array $a = [a_1, …, a_n]$.
>
> Question: is $a$ a sorted array?

This problem can easily be solved by a polynomial time function, something that would look like:

```
is_sorted(a):
    for i = 1 to n - 1:
        if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
            return false
    return true
```

That proves that $\texttt{SORTED} \in \mathsf{P}$: for a problem, there EXISTS a function running in polynomial time that solves this problem.

But you could also do it in a very stupid, complicated way, something like:

```
is_sorted(a):
    n = |a|
    if n ≤ 1:
        return true
    if n = 2:
        return a[1] ≤ a[2]
    for each proper subset I ⊊ {1, …, n}:
        define b as {a[i] | i ∈ I}
        if !is_sorted(b):
            return false
    return true
```

Now this function is correct (it will give the right answer to the question), but its running time is at least exponential, even with memoization.

Does that mean that $\texttt{SORTED} \in \mathsf{EXP}$? Absolutely! Because we found an exponential running time algorithm solving the problem.

Does that mean that $\texttt{SORTED}\notin \mathsf{P}$? Absolutely not! We previously proved that $\texttt{SORTED}\in \mathsf{P}$.

What I wanted to show here is that the **same** problem can results in **different** algorithms. But when we try to classify into complexity classes, we classify **problems**, not algorithms. As such, we want to find the best algorithm solving one problem.

What you tried to prove in your (complicated to understand because you confuse problems and functions) proof is that there exists an exponential time function solving a $\mathsf{NP}$ problem. But that does not mean that there is not a polynomial time function solving it!

Comment: Sorry, I see the error of this proof This post may be deleted by me latter. I am newbie. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @wij don't delete your post, it may be usefull for someone else in the future. If my answer or the answer of gnasher729 helped, consider upvoting or accepting one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not have shown that one particular function doesn't provide valid certificates (may or may not because it's not quite clear what you are saying). That's true for most functions. You haven't shown that no function *can* be used.

Comment: Not quite understand what you say. "if S∈ℙ, then, there exists a function F∈ℙ".
I.e. the certificate F exists WHEN one P-time S is provided. This proof says no such ℙ-time S can exist.

Comment: Sorry, I see the error of this proof This post may be deleted by me latter. I am newbie. Thanks for your answer.